# Getting Camera Resolutions Using Accord.Video.DirectShow

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, accord.net

I am evaluating the Accord.NET Framework (https://github.com/accord-net/framework/) for use in an imaging application. At the moment I have some basic requirements - capture video from a USB camera to display on the UI and view/change all camera properties.

Accord.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice.DisplayPropertyPage works well for showing the camera properties, such as brightness, contrast, hue etc. but does not show available camera resolutions.

Accord.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice.VideoCapabilities is returning only one resolution but I was expecting several more.

I have tried the VideoCapx (http://videocapx.com/) ActiveX control and using its ShowVideoFormatDlg method I can display a dialog which shows all available resolutions, framerates etc. I understand this is a dialog provided by the manufacturer and accessed via OLE\COM. What I am looking for is a way of accessing this via .NET, hopefully through the Accord framework.

I understand the additional resolutions might be properties of a transform filter however I am new to DirectShow and COM interfaces in .NET so I am looking for some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to wrap DirectShow code for .NET.
For sure with DirectShow it is possible to get, set ,and retrieve a/v source capabilities.
Have You tried using IAMStreamConfig video interface to set output format on certain capture and compression filters?

I use this code to get resolutions and set it on different sources.
where m_pVCap: source filter

```
hr = m_pBuilder->FindInterface(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,&MEDIATYPE_Interleaved,
               m_pVCap, IID_IAMVideoCompression,(void **)&m_pVC);

    if (hr != S_OK)
        hr = m_pBuilder->FindInterface(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video,
               m_pVCap,IID_IAMVideoCompression,(void **)&m_pVC);

    // !!! What if this interface isn't supported?
    // we use this interface to set the frame rate and get the capture size
    hr = m_pBuilder->FindInterface(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,&MEDIATYPE_Interleaved,
               m_pVCap, IID_IAMStreamConfig, (void **)&m_pVSC);
    if (hr != NOERROR) 
    {
        hr = m_pBuilder->FindInterface(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, 
          m_pVCap, IID_IAMStreamConfig,(void **)&m_pVSC);
        if (hr != NOERROR) 
        {
            LogDXError(hr, false, FILELINE);
        }
     }
```

To get current source format

```
hr = m_pVSC->GetFormat(&pmt);
    // DV capture does not use a VIDEOINFOHEADER
    if (hr == NOERROR) 
    {
        if (pmt->formattype == FORMAT_VideoInfo) 
        {   
            VIDEOINFOHEADER *pvi = (VIDEOINFOHEADER *)pmt->pbFormat;

            pvi->AvgTimePerFrame = (LONGLONG)(10000000 / m_FrameRate);

            hr = m_pVSC->SetFormat(pmt);

            if (hr != NOERROR)
                (NotifyNewError) (FILELINE, "", LOG_ALL, ERR_GRAVE, false,
                    "Cannot set frame rate for capture");

            hr = m_pVSC->GetFormat(&pmt);
            pvi = (VIDEOINFOHEADER *)pmt->pbFormat;

            pvi->bmiHeader.biWidth = g_SizeOutput.cx;
            pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight = g_SizeOutput.cy;
            pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = DIBSIZE(pvi->bmiHeader);

            hr = m_pVSC->SetFormat(pmt);
            if (hr != NOERROR)
            {
                char ErrTxt[MAX_ERROR_TEXT_LEN];                           
                AMGetErrorText(hr, ErrTxt,MAX_ERROR_TEXT_LEN);
                wsprintf(szError, "Error %x: %s\nCannot set frame rate (%d)for 
                   prev", hr, ErrTxt,m_FrameRate);
                (NotifyNewError)(FILELINE, "", LOG_ALL, ERR_GRAVE, false, szError);                 
             }

             DeleteMediaType(pmt);
        }
```

To get sources capabilities you can use:

```
IAMStreamConfig::GetNumberOfCapabilities and then IAMStreamConfig::GetStreamCaps
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Using C#.NET and the Accord.Video.DirectShow libraries, IAMStreamConfig.GetNumberOfCapabilities is returning only one resolution - the highest for the camera... so my suspicion is that the other resolutions shown when displaying the device driver format dialog are actually provided by a compression filter. I'm unsure how to get/set these programmatically. Any ideas?

Comment: For my experience DirectShow source filter not always implement any resolutions or frame rate or size supported by device.
In order to easily verify DirectShow  source filter capabilities I use to do it with Graph edit, before writing custom code.
Just download and install it, add source filter on it and look on capture pin properties to verified supported source capabilities.

Comment: I have managed to show the device video format dialog using IAMStreamConfig and ISpecifyPropertyPages which will do for now. I think you are correct that custom code must be written to pull out all supported capabilities that are not considered standard. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer to your own question, so future users can also benefit from it!